# regular expression replace string and except specific string

Tags: java, regex

```
String a = "This is a book! I am a boy. He is a good man. My friend Mrs. Roy is good man. He is nice person. Miss. Star is my friend.";
String b = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([.!?])( )([A-Z]+)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(a).replaceAll("$1$2 →$4");
```

The result is :

This is a book! →I am a boy. →He is a good man. →My friend Mrs. →Roy is good man. →He is nice person. →Miss. Star is my friend.

but What i want is:

This is a book! →I am a boy. →He is a good man. →My friend Mrs. Roy is good man. →He is nice person. →Miss. Star is my friend.

I don't want add the "→" after some string "Mr."、"Miss."、"Mrs."、"Ms.".
→ is tag the start of sentence.

Thanks~!

Comment: It is not that easy. You  have to account for all the possible abbreviations, and there are a lot of them. There are also quotations to deal with.

Comment: I think you may have to think more about your business rules:  I can see Miss. Star is my friend.  being 2 correct sentences, or being a young woman being your friend.  Even if you do specify Miss, Mr. etc. there will be some edge cases that will cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you desire to match a well written sentences in your test  you should first match Uppercase or Lowercase , then anything that is not a quotation and then one of them. 
And then not Match special groups Like Dr, Mr , Mrs and etc.

```
(([^.!?]|(?<=Dr|Mr|Mrs|\b[A-Za-z]|\s)[.!?])*[\.!?])
```

the explanation :

1st Capturing Group

```
(([^.!?]|(?<=Dr|Mr|Mrs|\b[A-Za-z]|\s)[.!?])*[\.!?])
```

2nd Capturing Group

```
([^.!?]|(?<=Dr|Mr|Mrs|\b[A-Za-z]|\s)[.!?])*

*
```

Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
1st Alternative

```
[^.!?]
```

Match a single character not present in the list .!?

2nd Alternative

```
(?<=Dr|Mr|Mrs|\b[A-Za-z]|\s)[.!?]
```

Positive Lookbehind

```
(?<=Dr|Mr|Mrs|\b[A-Za-z]|\s)
```

Assert that the Regex below matches

1st Alternatives

```
Dr|Mr|Mrs
```

Dr matches the characters Dr,Mr,Mrs literally (case sensitive)

2th Alternative

```
 \b[A-Za-z]\s
```

And both the groups

```
[.!?]
```

Match a single character present in the list .!?

[Regex Link](https://regex101.com/r/abqqrq/1/)